# replace invalid characters in http request body in a c# .net webservice

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, deserialization

I use aspera enterprise server/aspera connect for uploads from users. This solution offers a start/stop validation of those uploads and sends a JSON formatted http request to a webservice I can specify.

The problem is that all this is set up so aspera uses a domain user for authentication and this domain user is saved as "TD\asperaTransfer" and it seems I can't change the notation of the user and that the aspera software does not sanitize it's json before/while serializing the data.

This means my webservice gets a request with a body like this:

```
{
    "startstop": "stop",
    "session_id": "99eb1fac-da7b-41ac-83ee-b3c5f6973210",
    "host": "10.22.64.6",
    "client_ip": "10.20.21.80",
    "user": "TD\asperaTransfer",
    "user_id": "0",
    "direction": "recv",
    "target_rate_kbps": "1000",
    "min_rate_kbps": "0",
    "rate_policy": "fair",
    "cipher": "aes-128",
    "file": "F:\\UploadTest\\Penn and Teller explain Sleight of hand.mp4",
    "size": "2318300",
    "start_byte": "0",
    "end_byte": "2318300",
    "file_name_encoding": "utf8",
    "file_csum_type": "none",
    "cookie" : "True|c4308ab7-5772-4549-b2ae-8145d1e43230|master_cbc9d569-4154-4b10-8b3b-5fe8e68197b1.mp4"
}
```

As you can see the file path is escaped correctly. This is because another part of the software sets the file path in the request. Still the domain "\" is not escaped and thus every time .net tries to deserialize in any way I get a `XmlException` "Unexpected character 'a'".

So my question is:

Is there any way to either replace "TD\asperaTransfer" with the correctly escaped "TD\\asperaTransfer" or any way to not deserialize it, but just retrieve a string representation of the body that I can work with then?

My last try for this was to create a `MessageInspector` class that implements `IDispatchMessageInspector` and replace the body in the `AfterReceiveRequest()` method.

Still I have the problem that I got no idea how to get at the body contents without using some kind of deserializer that then would throw the `XmlException` again.

Edit:

So yes - the body is a json formatted string, but the way .NET receives HTTP Requests is as a Message object in a XML-Soap-Envelope, so to receive the body string I have to use a XML deserializer, but when I do that I get the XML Exception. Sorry for the XML/Json confusion.

I also think it's strange that I get an XML-Exception, but it says "Invalid character 'a'" - and if I test it with another request like TD\zoolander then it says the invalid character is 'z' so I assume it has to do with the backslash, although it doesn't count as escape character in XML.

If there is a way even before that to retrieve the HTTP Request and save it as a log so you can see it for debugging purposes - THAT is what I am trying to do, but can't get the .NET Framework to do it, because it wraps the HTTP Request in a Message object, and thus in XML.

I don't even need the whole body, just the value of the "cookie" key. The rest is useless to me, but even trying to just jump to that it iterates over TD\ and throws the exception.

Comment: You should create a C# (POCO) object and then use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` to format your object as JSON for the body.  MORE INFO: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Two things
**First:** If I could get a string representation of the body I wouldn't have the problem, so this deserializer that uses a string as input does not help me or I don't see how this helps me, since the Message class is always wrapped in XML and in the body of this message is the json formatted string. I can't retrieve this string without an exception. If I get the string It'd be easy.

**Second:** From the docu you linked - "Json.NET should be used serialization and deserialization. Provides serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications."

Comment: This is JSON, but you talk about getting an XML exception, and one with an unusual message at that (XML doesn't do anything with backslash escaping). What's the *entire* message body including wrapping, and what does your service binding look like?

Comment: Can you post the entire xml request and corresponding data contract?

Comment: I would love to get the entire xml request - If you can tell me how to retrieve/save it from the service?

Comment: you can try `Message.GetReaderAtBodyContents()` to get a `XmlDictionaryReader` and use `XmlDictionaryReader.ReadContentAsString()` to retrieve the body `xml`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing and either the String is empty or I get said exception.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was a custom content type mapper that I already had written for the webservice in the old datacenter in aspera, because the HTTP request also has no content-type set. So for .NET to deserialize the request I set the contenttype to JSON regardless of what was in the header.

For the messageInspector I set it back to raw (removing probably also would help)

In the AfterReceiveRequest I read the request like this now:

```
    private string ReadRawBody(ref Message message)
    {
        XmlDictionaryReader bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
        bodyReader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
        byte[] bodyBytes = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();
        string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyBytes);

        // Now to recreate the message 
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(ms);
        writer.WriteStartElement("Binary");
        writer.WriteBase64(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
        Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, message.Version);
        newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(message.Properties);
        message = newMessage;

        return messageBody;
    }
```

With this string representation of the body I can work, replace the TD\asperaTransfer and then process the request like I used to.

The problem was a custom content type mapper that always set the content type to json and thus .NET tried to deserialize it as json it seems. Thanks for the questions for clarification the comments about "\" not being a special character and what the service contract is made me look up the right things.